# UTF-8 encoding issue of JSONSerialization

Tags: swift, encoding, nsjsonserialization

I was trying convert `struct` to `Dictionary` in Swift. This was my code:

```
extension Encodable {

    var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) {
            if let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] {
                return dict
            }
            return nil
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

This works in most situation. But when I try to convert a nested structure  which contains unicode characters such as Chinese, this happened:

```
struct PersonModel: Codable {
    var job: String?
    var contacts: [ContactSimpleModel]
    var manager: ManagerSimpleModel?
}

struct ContactSimpleModel: Codable {
    var relation: String
    var name: String
}

struct ManagerSimpleModel: Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

let contact1 = ContactSimpleModel(relation: "朋友", name: "宙斯")
let contact2 = ContactSimpleModel(relation: "同学", name: "奥丁")
let manager = ManagerSimpleModel(name: "拉斐尔", age: 31)
let job = "火枪手"

let person = PersonModel(job: job, contacts: [contact1, contact2], manager: manager)

if let dict = person.dictionary {
    print(dict)
}
```

The result of this code is this:

```
["contacts": <__NSArrayI 0x600002471980>(
{
    name = "\U5b99\U65af";
    relation = "\U670b\U53cb";
},
{
    name = "\U5965\U4e01";
    relation = "\U540c\U5b66";
}
)
, "manager": {
    age = 31;
    name = "\U62c9\U6590\U5c14";
}, "job": 火枪手]
```

You can see the result. The Chinese characters in those nested structures were become a utf-8 encoding string. The top-level property `"job": 火枪手` is right. But the values in those nested structures were not the original string.

Is this a bug of `JSONSerialization`? Or how to make it right?

More information. I used the result like this:

```
var sortedQuery = ""

if let dict = person.dictionary {
    sortedQuery = dict.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
        .map({ "\($0)\($1)" })
        .joined(separator: "")
}
```

It was used to check whether the query was legal. The result is not the same as Java or other platform.

Comment: It's a plist-like notation used by `NSDictionary`. You have no need to worry, it holds internal `NSString` as in your original data.

Comment: Hello! Maybe you can try to get the `Data` of your JSON string by doing `jsonString.data(using: .utf8)` and then `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions)`?

Comment: **_The result is not the same as Java_** It does not make sense without showing your Java code.

Comment: @IMACODE Thanks for your reply. But I want to convert from a `struct`, not a json string. This is the easiest way I've ever found.

Comment: @OOPer I compared with the result of Java. The only different thing is the encoding of the nested structures' string property. Java prints the original characters, but Swift shows the encoding string.

Comment: So, please show your Java code.

Comment: @OOPer Java code is here https://gist.github.com/hisoka0917/d5b941233b20ba75732c2c79e29d7121 the result of this piece of code is `contactsname宙斯relation朋友name奥丁relation同学job火枪手managerage31name拉斐尔` and the md5 is `c734a494d015e55c6bc6b4ba6a53d3a8`. The result of Swift code is `contactsname\U5b99\U65afrelation\U670b\U53cbname\U5965\U4e01relation\U540c\U5b66job火枪手managerage31name\U62c9\U6590\U5c14` and md5 is `f673b816668a2a65bfee0557b89ac4e3`

Comment: The link you have shown shows 404 page.

Comment: And if your code is not so big, you should better include it in the text of your question.

Comment: @OOPer I updated the code here, it's big  https://bitbucket.org/mnxheng/jsonsortdemo/src/master/src/main/java/JsonSortDemo.java . Github have some problems today.

Comment: I believe 72 lines is not so big. You should better include it into your question's text. And your Java code has many complex processing including regex. I really do not understand why you expect String interpolation of Swift would ever generate the same output. Update your question as to include the Java code. Someone can show you some equivalent code of Swift with as complex processing as your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

The result is perfectly fine. That's the internal string representation – a pre-Unicode legacy – of an array or dictionary when you `print` it.

Assign the values to a label or text view and you will see the expected characters.

Comment: Yes, It could display correct. But my actual usage is like this `let checksum = dict.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
        .map({ "\($0)\($1)" })
        .joined(separator: "")`. The result is not the same as the server and other platforms. It was used to check whether the params are legal.